# How to export a class from one .js file to another .js file, with a method which has a function in it

Tags: javascript, class, export

So I have a class called Movie, which creates an object with the movie's various details.
Within the method "displayMovieDetails", I'm using another function "toHoursAndMinutes" to convert the movie's runtime from only mins to hours & mins.

class (creates an object with the movie's various details):

```
class movie{
    constructor (name, genre, runTime, releaseDate, rating){
        this.name = name;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.runTime = runTime;
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
        this.rating = rating;
    }
    displayMovieDetails(){
        console.log(`\n\nName\t\t: ${this.name}\nGenre\t\t: ${this.genre}\nRunning Time\t: ${func.toHoursAndMinutes(this.runTime)}\nRelease Date\t: ${this.releaseDate}\nRating\t\t: ${this.rating[0] === 0? 0: (this.rating[1]/this.rating[0]).toFixed(1)} (${this.rating[0]} voters)\n`);
    }
}
```

Method (to display the details of all the new movie objects created, in a certain manner):

```
displayMovieDetails(){
        console.log(`\n\nName\t\t: ${this.name}\nGenre\t\t: ${this.genre}\nRunning Time\t: ${func.toHoursAndMinutes(this.runTime)}\nRelease Date\t: ${this.releaseDate}\nRating\t\t: ${this.rating[0] === 0? 0: (this.rating[1]/this.rating[0]).toFixed(1)} (${this.rating[0]} voters)\n`);
    }
```

Function (is a function within the method highlighted before, whose purpose is to convert the movie's runtime from only mins to hours & mins - this function has already been imported from another file, hence its func.toHoursAndMinutes() ):

```
toHoursAndMinutes: function(totalMinutes){
        const minutes = totalMinutes % 60;
    const hours = Math.floor(totalMinutes / 60);
  //if the movie is a perfect hour, it will display only the hours, otherwise display hours and minutes
    return `${hours}h${minutes > 0 ? ` ${minutes}mins` : ''}`;
    },
```

I want to export the class into another file, but I get a error when I try to do it.
I use this way to export the class from file A:
`module.exports = {}`
I use this way to import the class and toHoursAndMinutes function into file B:
`var func = require("./appFunctions");`

I just want to shift the class from my main .js file to a separate file, to make my main.js file more streamlined.

I think the error comes in because of the toHoursAndMinutes function that is within the class method.

Comment: How do you export `toHoursAndMinutes()`?

Comment: @Geshode I put it inside of the curly braces of module.exports{}. using functioname : function(){ ... } format